# Change UICollectionView Height Dynamically according to cell's not change cell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am developing IOS App.Click to Tableview cell Than value show on collectionViewCell but I want change collectionView height according to cell's.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(_collectionView.frame.size.width , _collectionView.frame.size.height+30);

}
```

Comment: You want to change collection view height or cell height??

Comment: Do you want to change collectionView height based on cell count?

Comment: yes change collectionview height based on cell count

Answer (score 2):

you can change it by using contentSize of its scrollView
after the collectionview is loaded.. if you update any cell insert items or delete items you need to update height again
i.e.

```
myCollectionView.reload()
```

now updating frame or height

```
//if you are using auto-resizing you can update frame
let frame = myCollectionView.frame
frame.height = myCollectionView.contentSize.height
myCollectionView.frame = frame
```

and if you are using autolayout make and iboutlet for your collectionview's height constraint

```
@IBOutlet collectionViewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutContraint!
```

now update this contraint

```
collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = myCollectionView.contentSize.height
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    var numberOfCellInRow : Int = yourArray.count
    var padding : Int = 5
    var collectionCellWidth : CGFloat = (self.view.frame.size.width/CGFloat(numberOfCellInRow)) - CGFloat(padding)
    return CGSize(width: collectionCellWidth , height: collectionCellWidth)
}
```